# Reason for unsupported format error with OpenCV's .findContours() function despite binary input

Tags: python, opencv

I am attempting to detect the difference in motion between two frames in a video. After calculating the difference between values in each frame (diff_frame) the image is diluted and filtered with cv.threshold. This should convert it to a binary format as I am using type=THRESH_BINARY.

However, when I use the new binary thresh_frame gererated in the cv.findContours function it returns error:

> (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats).
> [Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode !=
> CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function
> 'cvStartFindContours_Impl'

Main code loop below:

```
filename = os.fsdecode(file)
frame_count = 0
previous_frame = None
ipath = data+"/"+filename
cap = cv.VideoCapture(ipath)

while True:
    frame_count += 1

    img = cap.read()

    prepared_frame = cv.cvtColor(img[1], cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    prepared_frame = cv.GaussianBlur(src=prepared_frame, ksize=(5,5), sigmaX=0)

    if (frame_count == 1):
        previous_frame = prepared_frame
        continue
                    
    diff_frame = cv.absdiff(src1=previous_frame, src2=prepared_frame)
    previous_frame = prepared_frame
                

    kernel = np.ones((5, 5))
    diff_frame = cv.dilate(diff_frame, kernel, 1)

    thresh_frame = cv.threshold(src=diff_frame, thresh=20, maxval=255, type=cv.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    contours = cv.findContours(image=thresh_frame, mode=cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, method=cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

The exception occurs on the last line calling cv.findContours(). I cant see why the error is being caused as the previous cv.threshold call should have converted the input to a binary format.

I am using OpenCV(4.7.0) and Python 3

Comment: You cannot used keyword image.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is that you are passing to `findContours`, is not a binary image (one channel/8 bit-depth). Looking carefully at the code, the second argument of `cv.cvtColor` is wrong, that is not a [color conversion code](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0)... Well, it is an `enum`, but the encoded integer probably doesn't map to the conversion you expect. The correct conversion code from BGR to Grayscale is `cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`, so the fixed line becomes: `prepared_frame = cv2.cvtColor(img[1], cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`.

Answer (score -2):

please provide a minimal, selfcontained example of your problem next time. e.g. put all the imports needed and create a testfile yourself.

to answer your question the problem is that contaours needs uint8 and not only binary as filetype

## Ensure thresh_frame is uint8

```
 thresh_frame = thresh_frame.astype(np.uint8)
```

you could also use threshold like [in the documentation example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html):

```
imgray = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
```

your threshhold is too low.